# OpenLayers 3 get interaction draw style

Tags: openlayers

After creating a draw interaction:

```
var draw = new ol.interaction.Draw({
        source: vector.getSource(),
        type: /** @type {ol.geom.GeometryType} */ ('Polygon'),
      });
```

Is there a way to get its Style? In this case it would be the default Style.